# Encrypt string with openssl_public_encrypt() in PHP and decrypt in optiga trust m ic with arduino

Tags: php, arduino, cryptography, rsa

I generated key pairs with optiga trust m IC with arduino. [Here is the lib](https://github.com/Infineon/arduino-optiga-trust-m)
It output the public key as below

```
Generate Key Pair RSA 1024. Store Private Key on Board ...
[OK] | Command executed in 799 ms
Public Key Length: 144
Public Key :
0x000000: 03 81 8d 00 30 81 89 02 81 81 00 9d df 7c 3f a3 ....0........|?.
0x000010: 34 28 5e 2d be de 05 f6 7e c7 8a ab c8 47 c2 8f 4(^-........G..
0x000020: 14 85 c5 30 59 59 28 8a 3c 7a 1c f3 67 5f 44 dc ...0YY(.<z..g_D.
0x000030: f6 1b c7 4e 7e c7 f2 5a e3 f4 19 51 ca 31 d0 b8 ...N..Z...Q.1..
0x000040: a7 6e 7f a7 82 f1 5b 48 dc ab 04 b1 23 96 7b c7 .n....[H....#.{.
0x000050: ad 2b 24 e7 e6 aa 83 61 14 04 4a 82 4f 32 3f 61 .+$....a..J.O2?a
0x000060: 3e c6 6e fc e2 03 db ae 07 95 82 b1 01 ae ef 19 >.n.............
0x000070: 3f 8e cf 25 07 f0 b3 d6 08 05 ea 38 be 33 74 6a ?..%.......8.3tj
0x000080: 3a 54 78 68 b2 d9 47 67 1d f2 a1 02 03 01 00 01 :Txh..Gg........
```

I want to use this public key in [openssl_public_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) function with PHP.
but the key format is not accepted with the function. How can I format the above public key in order to use in PHP. I am getting this error

```
openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: That is a stack trace of the key in assembly, you need the value of the key.. Perhaps this lib stores it somewhere or comes with the ability to store it in a file?

Comment: Without the first 4 bytes this is a public key in PKCS#1 format: 0x308189...010001. `openssl_public_encrypt()` needs a public key in X.509/SPKI format. If you need to use this key, you can convert it e.g. with OpenSSL: `openssl rsa -pubout -RSAPublicKey_in -inform der -in public_pkcs1.der -out x509.pem`. Here `public_pkcs1.der` is the PKCS#1 key, i.e. your key without the first 4 bytes and `x509.pem` is the X.509/SPKI key needed for `openssl_public_encrypt()`.

Comment: https://github.com/Infineon/optiga-trust-m/wiki/Data-format-examples#RSA-Public-Key This is the key format explanation

Comment: I try to convert by taking without 4 bytes via below openssl command
openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in pub1.pub -inform DER -outform PEM -out pubkey.pem -RSAPublicKey_out
unable to load Public Key
140690741830976:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140690741830976:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=RSAPublicKey